# How do I filter results that the Ember Data store has already fetched?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I know I can do:

```
this.questions = this.store.find('FaqQuestion', {category: 42);
```

However, if I'm displaying multiple sections of the FAQ on a page, I'll want to do:

```
this.questions = this.store.find('FaqQuestion');
```

But how do I then filter those questions based on the category?

FaqQuestion is a DS model:

```
App.FaqQuestion = DS.Model.extend({
    question: DS.attr('string'),
    answer: DS.attr('string'),
    target: function () {
        return '#' + this.get('id');
    }.property('id')
});
```

I've tried this (in an ObjectController):

```
deliveryQuestions: function () {
    return this.questions.filterProperty('category', 42);
}.property('deliveryQuestions')
```

And various permeations to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to define category on your model

#### Record

```
App.FaqQuestion = DS.Model.extend({
    question: DS.attr('string'),
    answer: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.attr(),
    target: function () {
        return '#' + this.get('id');
    }.property('id')
});
```

#### Filter already fetched records

```
var coolFaqsCollection = this.store.filter('faqQuestion', function(record){
  return record.get('category') == 42;
});
```

#### Example

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/445/edit

Answer (score 1):

You should define the category relationship at your Question model

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({

});

App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    category: DS.belongsTo('category'),
    answer: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Once, you have fetched your question content, you have at least two possibilities to filter the content based on a specific category id.

```
this.controller.filter(function(record){
   return record.get('category.id') === "42";
});

this.get('store').filter('question', function(record){
   return record.get('category.id') === "42";  
});
```

Check the [demo example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/paqaf/2/edit).